# Вывести ошибки при регистрации

Tags: php

Регистрируясь может допустить ошибки, нужно что бы все допущеные пользователем ошибки выводились, ниже скрипт выводит только по одной

```
function output_errors($errors){
      $errors = implode("<br>",$errors);
    return '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>',$errors) . '</li></ul>';

    }
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        if(empty($fn)){
        $errors[]= "заполните имя";
        }
        elseif(empty($ln)){
        $errors[]= "заполните фамилию";
        }elseif(empty($un)){
        $errors[]= "заполните логин";
        }elseif(empty($em)){
        $errors[]= "заполните email";
        }elseif(empty($pswd)){
        $errors[]= "пароль не должен быть пустым";
        }elseif(!filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors[]= "введите корректно email";
        }elseif(email_exists($em)==true){
        $errors[]= "$em используется";
        }elseif($em!=$em2){
        $errors[]= "email должен совпадать с введеным";
        }elseif(strlen($pswd)<6 or strlen($pswd)>32){
        $errors[]= "пароль должен быть больше 6 и меньше 32 символов";
        }elseif($pswd!=$pswd2){
        $errors[]= "пароли дожны совпадать";
        }elseif(user_exists($un)==true){
        $errors[]= "$un уже используется";
        }elseif(strpos($un,0x20)!=false){
        $errors[]= "логин не должен содержать пробелы";
        }elseif(strlen($un)<6 or strlen($un)>32){
        $errors[]= "Логин должен быть не меньше 6 символов и не больше 32";
        }elseif(strlen($fn)<3 or strlen($fn)>32){
        $errors[]= "имя должно быть не меньше 3 символов и не больше 32";
        }elseif(strlen($ln)<3 or strlen($ln)>32){
        $errors[]= "Фамилия должна быть не меньше 3 символов и не больше 32";
        }else{
         $query = array (
         'username'    => trim($_POST['username']),
         'password'    => $_POST['password'],
         'first_name'  => trim($_POST['fname']),
         'last_name'   => trim($_POST['lname']),
         'email'       => $_POST['email'],
         'email_code'  => md5($_POST['username']+ microtime()),
         'bio'         => 'write somesing'

         );

         register_user($query);// отправляет на ємейл сгенерированный код
        die("<h2>регистрация завершена, активируйтесь</h2>");

        }
         if(empty($errors)===false){
         echo output_errors($errors);//выводит ошибки
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите `elseif`, замените на `else`, в массив `$errors` кидайте ключ ошибки и её обозначение, потом смотрите массив, если он пустой, то рег., нет, то выводите сообщение об ошибке

```
if(empty($_POST['lname']))
{
 $error[1] = 'Введите логин';
}
if(empty($_POST['email']))
{
 $error[2] = 'Введите емайл';
}
и так далее
Потом:
if(!empty($error))
{
 foreach($error as $value)
 {
  echo 'Ошибка:'.$value;
 }
}
else
{
 // Заносим в базу
}
```

Comment: Уберите elseif где же я условия буду задавать?

Comment: все спасибо заработало)))